# iBeacon: can broadcaster iOS device get notified if client receives a beacon or enters its region?

Tags: ibeacon

I have two iOS devices; one is sending beacons using peripheralManager, beaconPeripheralData, etc. The second, a receiver device, is currently scanning for regions and beacons of the same UUID using didEnterRegion, didRangeBeacons, etc.

Is there any method or callback for the -broadcaster- side to know if the scanning side has entered its region or received its beacon? Something similar to "didEnterRegion", but for the broadcaster.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer - no.
Not so simple answer - clients don't connect to the "broadcaster", they just listen for advertisements, so there is no way for "broadcasters" to identify who has "heard" them.

Answer (score 2):

Vladimir's answer is correct. However, you can set up your "broadcaster" (advertiser, in BLE terms) to also listen for other BLE devices that are advertising services, or sending out iBeacon broadcasts.

Then you would set up the remote receiving iOS app to execute special code when it gets a didEnterRegion call. That code could start advertising a pre-defined BLE service that your "broadcaster" is already listening for, and the two devices could then enter into a 2-way BLE conversation.

More simply, your receiver could simply start sending it's own beacon signal when it gets a didEnterRegion message as a result of detecting the "broadcaster"'s beacon signal.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking about. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this is you just use CoreBluetooth CBCentral and CBPeripheral rather than trying to be an iBeacon (which encourages non-connectability).

While there is no standard way for a broadcaster or peripheral to automatically know who's found it you can do this by having an service and characteristic on your iOS peripheral. You could have your central scan for a particular UUID and when it finds it, have it connect and write an attribute, and then disconnect. This would give your peripheral information about who saw it.

This avoids the issue where you try to toggle between one device being a broadcaster and a central, since you can't be both of them at the same time.